# Ruby on Rails: How to include YAML content in a fixture?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I'm using the IceCube gem to build meeting recurrences and I want to include a recurrence schedule in a meetings.yml fixture.

When I include the following YAML content in the recurrence attribute in the meetings.yml fixture, the rest of the fixtures simply don't load.

```
---
:start_time: 2020-05-21 12:00:00.000000000 -06:00
:end_time: 2020-05-21 12:15:00.000000000 -06:00
:rrules:
- :validations:
    :day:
    - 1
  :rule_type: IceCube::WeeklyRule
  :interval: 1
  :week_start: 0
- :validations:
    :day:
    - 2
  :rule_type: IceCube::WeeklyRule
  :interval: 1
  :week_start: 0
:rtimes: []
:extimes: []
```

Any thoughts on how I could approach populating my fixtures with this data?

Answer (score 0):

Block style indicator in the [literal style did the trick](https://yaml-multiline.info/).

```
meeting:
  start_date: <%= Time.current + 5.days %>
  recurrence: |+
    ---
    :start_time: 2020-05-21 12:00:00.000000000 -06:00
    :end_time: 2020-05-21 12:15:00.000000000 -06:00
    :rrules:
    - :validations:
        :day:
        - 1
      :rule_type: IceCube::WeeklyRule
      :interval: 1
      :week_start: 0
    - :validations:
        :day:
        - 2
      :rule_type: IceCube::WeeklyRule
      :interval: 1
      :week_start: 0
    :rtimes: []
    :extimes: []
```